# Пакет компилируется, но не создаются файлы .class

Tags: intellij-idea, компиляция

В Intellij IDEA пакет компилируется успешно, но не запускается - и скомпилированные файлы .class тоже я не вижу (и IDE не находит главный класс PersonTest.class, потому что его просто нет !) Ни по указанному пути, ни вообще на диске по поиску.
Вот главный класс:

```
package abstractClasses;

public class PersonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person[] people = new Person[2];

        // fill the people array with Student and Employee objects
        people[0] = new Employee("Harry Hacker", 50000, 1989, 10, 1);
        people[1] = new Student("Maria Morris", "computer science");

        // print out names and descriptions of all Person objects
        for (Person p : people)
            System.out.println(p.getName() + ", " + p.getDescription());
    }
}
```

Comment: а как настроен проект в IDEA?

Comment: имеются в виду настройки в меню File/Project Structure ?

Comment: да, а так же тип проекта.

Comment: тип проекта Application;

Comment: Project structure/Project: 
Project name: CoreJava
Project SDK: 1.8
Project language level: 8
Project compiler output: D:\DownLoadFirefox\corejava\corejava\v1ch05\abstractClasses

Comment: можно задать вопрос по-другому: какие должны быть настройки и тип проекта, чтобы он выполнялся - т.е.выводились бы результаты System.out.println ? Я изучаю Java по книжке, и беру с сайта книги примеры кода - хочу разобраться с ними

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.